# Average Annual Growth Rate with moving length R

Tags: r, dplyr

Given the structure of my data below, I would like to calculate the forward five years average annual growth rate (where the first year is `lead(markup)` of the column `markup` for each individual (individual are identified in the column `(gvkey)`), and add to the data frame that average as a column. However, some individuals have less than five years observations, and for all individuals', their last 4 years observations, have less than 5 years of observations ahead of them. For those cases, the average annual growth rate should adjust to the number of observation ahead of them (with a maximum of 5).

```r
dput(example)
structure(list(gvkey = c(1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1003L, 1003L, 1003L, 
1003L, 1003L, 1003L, 1003L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 
1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 
1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L), fyear = c(1983L, 1984L, 
1985L, 1983L, 1984L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 1989L, 1980L, 
1981L, 1982L, 1983L, 1984L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 1989L, 
1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 
1999L), markup = c(3.02456418383518, 2.91714600416106, 2.97620103473762, 
0.628645648836935, 0.538264738598443, 0.74536402337831, 0.89905329776662, 
0.571759161863088, 0.510497237569061, 0.621391904401246, 0.320146680750145, 
0.277978758953348, 0.31442332968701, 0.319433516915814, 0.324865816687745, 
0.335264348013352, 0.328048313395744, 0.326632245360565, 0.340874293859881, 
0.320374201245953, 0.27456562124358, 0.276693369097675, 0.245072145096866, 
0.241026046834387, 0.242841330851661, 0.249635000371186, 0.257903948772679, 
0.262641379065405, 0.261534064206543, 0.22953354130982)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -30L), groups = structure(list(
    gvkey = c(1001L, 1003L, 1004L), .rows = structure(list(1:3, 
        4:10, 11:30), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .drop = TRUE))
```

This is as far as I got:

```
example %>%
  filter(fyear %in% 1980:2019)%>%
  group_by((gvkey))%>%
  mutate(markupchange = ((((lead(markup)-markup)/markup)+(lead(markup, K =2)-lead(markup)/lead(markup))+(lead(markup, K =3)-lead(markup, k =2)/lead(markup, K=2))+(lead(markup, K =4)-lead(markup, k =3)/lead(markup, K=3))+(lead(markup, K =5)-lead(markup, k =4)/lead(markup, K=4))/5)))
```

What I can't figure out how to indicate is to shorten the lenght of the average annual growth rate for thoses cases with less than 5 observations ahead.

As an ouput I would like to get back the same data frame with the extra column for the average annual growth rate of the `markup`.
The value in row 1 of the added column should be -0,00628231878798876 and in the second row 0,020547945.
Many thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your system is complaining about the size of your data, I'm going to recommend a non-join method (see the answer history for the first cut on this).

1. It is a bespoke function for each group, so it internally determines which data and the mean;
2. If necessary (based on memory complaints), I will suggest a `data.table` variant. I'll also provide the `dplyr` version that works with this data, but it may not work with your larger data, in which case `data.table` (with its in-place referential semantics) will be preferred.

First, a quick helper-function:

```r
fun <- function(mkup, fyr, span=5) {
  sapply(fyr, function(yr) {
    val <- mkup[between(fyr, yr, yr+span)]
    mean(c(diff(val), NA) / val, na.rm = TRUE)
  })
}
```

noting that `between` can be from either `dplyr` or `data.table`, they are equivalent in this use.

```r
### data.table
library(data.table)
EX <- as.data.table(example)
EX[, avg5 := fun(markup, fyear), by = gvkey]
### (same result as below)

### dplyr
example %>%
  group_by(gvkey) %>%
  mutate(avg5 = fun(markup, fyear)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 30 × 4
#    gvkey fyear markup      avg5
#    <int> <int>  <dbl>     <dbl>
#  1  1001  1983  3.02   -0.00764
#  2  1001  1984  2.92    0.0202 
#  3  1001  1985  2.98  NaN      
#  4  1003  1983  0.629  -0.00480
#  5  1003  1984  0.538   0.0674 
#  6  1003  1985  0.745  -0.0119 
#  7  1003  1986  0.899  -0.0847 
#  8  1003  1987  0.572   0.0550 
#  9  1003  1988  0.510   0.217  
# 10  1003  1989  0.621 NaN      
# # … with 20 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: hi, thanks!
what do you mean by non-equi join method? (sorry I'm not into the jargon at all)
And also, what I nead is the 5 year forward average annual growth rate, so in row 3 the value of the added column should be NA.

Comment: the value in row 1 of the added column should be -0,033112583 and in the second row 0,020547945

Comment: For most uses, the premise of a [merge/join](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/3358272) is based on equality, but the true calculus of it can be true inequalities (`>`, `<=`, ...) with potentially explosive (number of rows) results. In this case, when we join `example` on itself, we do it by `"gvkey"` and `fyear` between `fyear` and `fy5`; this results in a much-larger (close to 5x the number of rows) dataset which we must then summarize back to the original rows (ergo the need to add `rn` in the beginning).

Comment: Okay, I see you want percentage growth. Please edit your original question to add an expected value for at least some of your rows.

Comment: edited again for a correction in the results

Comment: See my edit @AyozeAlfageme, I think it's closer. I wonder if your expected value of `0,00628231878798876` (from the question, not from your comment above) is different due to rounding and calculating manually, which I can reproduce with `mean(c((2.92-3.02)/3.02, (2.98-2.92)/2.92))` though the real values in the frame have more digits and therefore a different gain.

Comment: but what I want is the Average Annual growth rate of the next 5 years. So GR1= growth rate next years, GR2= growth rate two years ahead, etc... so the average annual growth rate would be = (GR1 +GR2 +GR3 +GR4+GR5)/5

Comment: Please demonstrate how what I calculated here is incorrect. For example, `gvkey==1001` (top 3 rows) gives us: `filter(example, gvkey==1003) %>% summarize(GR1=(markup[2]-markup[1])/markup[1], GR2=(markup[3]-markup[2])/markup[2], GR3=(markup[3]-markup[2])/markup[2], GR4=(markup[4]-markup[3])/markup[3], GR5=(markup[5]-markup[4])/markup[4])`. This produces GRs of `-0.144 0.385 0.206 -0.364 -0.107` (all numbers here are rounded for print, real-float underneath). Averaging those is `-0.00480` (again, rounded from real-floats), which is what my answer produces. What am I missing?

Comment: (I started saying `1001` but calculated on `1003`, sorry for the mistype above ... it's all on 1003.)

Comment: yes, I realized. All good.

Comment: I am now using the code for a much larger dataframe but I only get NaN after row 30. Is the code cap to 30 rows or something like that?

Comment: I am sorry for asking those questions above, but I don't quite understand the full code, which makes it quite unwidely for me to change it. I don't understand why it does not work for a larger database...

Comment: *"after row 30"* doesn't give me a lot, is that the first 30 rows of the whole frame, or 30 rows per `gvkey`? See my edit, it explains a bit more.

Comment: 30 rows of the whole frame

Comment: When I upload a larger file (+200,000 rows), R gives me the message that the vector of large size cannot be allocated. I guess my computer is not powerful enough. Is there any way to make the computation more efficient?

Comment: I didn't think 200,000 would be a problem, since at most it expands to 1Mi rows (which is generally fine in R with reasonable amount of RAM on the system). However, I've made a (significantly-different) edit to the answer, see if that makes sense.

Comment: I does make sense and my computer goes through quite fast. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `frollmean()` which might be more computationally efficient.

First we need a helper to create rolling partial windows for use in `frollmean()`.
We'll use it to set bounds on the window sizes based on the group sizes.

```r
# Get rolling window sizes, including partial
window_seq <- function(k, n, partial = TRUE){
  if (length(k) != 1L) stop("k must be of length 1.")
  if (length(n) != 1L) stop("n must be of length 1.")
  if (n > .Machine[["integer.max"]]){
    stop("n must not be greater than .Machine$integer.max")
  }
  n <- as.integer(n)
  k <- as.integer(k)
  k <- min(k, n) # Bound k to <= n
  k <- max(k, 0L) # Bound k to >= 0
  pk <- max(k - 1L, 0L) # Partial k, bounded to >= 0
  p_seq <- seq_len(pk) # Partial window sequence
  out <- rep_len(k, n)
  # Replace partial part with partial sequence
  if (partial){
    out[p_seq] <- p_seq
  } else {
    out[p_seq] <- NA_integer_
  }
  out
}
```

## data.table

```
library(data.table)

# data.table
example2 <- copy(example)
setDT(example2)

example2[, pchange := (markup/shift(markup)) - 1,
         by = gvkey]
example2[, row_id := rowid(gvkey)]
setorderv(example2, c("gvkey", "row_id"), order = c(1L, -1L))
example2[, avg5 := frollmean(shift(pchange), n = window_seq(5, .N),
                             adaptive = T, na.rm = T),
         by = gvkey]
setorderv(example2, c("gvkey", "row_id"))
print(example2, n = 10)
#>     gvkey fyear    markup      pchange row_id         avg5
#>  1:  1001  1983 3.0245642           NA      1 -0.007635573
#>  2:  1001  1984 2.9171460 -0.035515259      2  0.020244112
#>  3:  1001  1985 2.9762010  0.020244112      3          NaN
#>  4:  1003  1983 0.6286456           NA      1 -0.004802629
#>  5:  1003  1984 0.5382647 -0.143770836      2  0.067397285
#> ---                                                       
#> 26:  1004  1995 0.2496350  0.027975755     16 -0.018769986
#> 27:  1004  1996 0.2579039  0.033124155     17 -0.036068033
#> 28:  1004  1997 0.2626414  0.018368972     18 -0.063286535
#> 29:  1004  1998 0.2615341 -0.004216072     19 -0.122356998
#> 30:  1004  1999 0.2295335 -0.122356998     20          NaN
```

## dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
example %>%
  group_by(gvkey) %>%
  mutate(pchange = (markup/lag(markup)) - 1) %>%
  mutate(row_id = row_number()) %>%
  arrange(desc(row_id), .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(avg5 = frollmean(lag(pchange), n = window_seq(5, n()), 
                          adaptive = T, na.rm = T)) %>%
  arrange(row_id, .by_group = TRUE)
#> # A tibble: 30 x 6
#> # Groups:   gvkey [3]
#>    gvkey fyear markup pchange row_id      avg5
#>    <int> <int>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <int>     <dbl>
#>  1  1001  1983  3.02  NA           1  -0.00764
#>  2  1001  1984  2.92  -0.0355      2   0.0202 
#>  3  1001  1985  2.98   0.0202      3 NaN      
#>  4  1003  1983  0.629 NA           1  -0.00480
#>  5  1003  1984  0.538 -0.144       2   0.0674 
#>  6  1003  1985  0.745  0.385       3  -0.0119 
#>  7  1003  1986  0.899  0.206       4  -0.0847 
#>  8  1003  1987  0.572 -0.364       5   0.0550 
#>  9  1003  1988  0.510 -0.107       6   0.217  
#> 10  1003  1989  0.621  0.217       7 NaN      
#> # i 20 more rows
```

For actual "growth rates", one can use geometric mean of percent changes which gives you the expected percent change per unit time.

```
# Growth rates
example %>%
  group_by(gvkey) %>%
  mutate(pchange = (markup/lag(markup))) %>%
  mutate(row_id = row_number()) %>%
  arrange(desc(row_id), .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(growth_rate5 = exp(frollmean(log(lag(pchange)), n = window_seq(5, n()),
                                      adaptive = T, na.rm = T)) - 1) %>%
  arrange(row_id, .by_group = TRUE)
#> # A tibble: 30 x 6
#> # Groups:   gvkey [3]
#>    gvkey fyear markup pchange row_id growth_rate5
#>    <int> <int>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <int>        <dbl>
#>  1  1001  1983  3.02   NA          1     -0.00803
#>  2  1001  1984  2.92    0.964      2      0.0202 
#>  3  1001  1985  2.98    1.02       3    NaN      
#>  4  1003  1983  0.629  NA          1     -0.0408 
#>  5  1003  1984  0.538   0.856      2      0.0291 
#>  6  1003  1985  0.745   1.38       3     -0.0445 
#>  7  1003  1986  0.899   1.21       4     -0.116  
#>  8  1003  1987  0.572   0.636      5      0.0425 
#>  9  1003  1988  0.510   0.893      6      0.217  
#> 10  1003  1989  0.621   1.22       7    NaN      
#> # i 20 more rows
```